# stack level deep too error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have installed Ruby 1.9.2 with RVM on my system. When I am trying to start the rails server I am getting the following error:

```
/Desktop/projects/mod/feedback$ ./script/server 

internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require:29: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

It works perfectly with ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Need to see what caused this error.. Show those attempts also.

Comment: You did install RVM and Ruby version 1.9.2, not RVM version 1.9.2 ??

Comment: its a ruby version installed via RVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your response. I got the solution for the above issue. Updating my system gem to 1.8.25 would fix my issue.

```
  gem update --system 1.8.25
```

Answer (score 0):

The error caused because of your session have less data store length.

If you are using MySQL then just change the column name data(varchar) to data(longtext) inside session table.

This change was solve my problem.

Comment: we are using Oracle database.

Comment: I didn't use oracle database with rails but if there is a table name with session then make changes as described.

Comment: no there in no table as session. and one more thing is its working fine with ruby 1.8.7